# Tomcat 9 error - mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup

Tags: java, tomcat, mysql-connector

I have a program that running in Tomcat 9.

When I restarted the problem, it shows the above warning:

```
05-Feb-2021 09:48:34.211 WARNING [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [AWSApps] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.trackLastModified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:963)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:941)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1057)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Tomcat Version : Tomcat 9
JVM : java-8-openjdk-amd64
Mysql Driver : mysql-connector-java-8.0.20

server.xml

```
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

I have tried to change the server.xml into

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

But there is still warning in Catalina.out.

Is there any guide to solve the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your application also come with `mysql-connector-java.jar`? Is it the only warning from the `*LeakPreventionListener`s? Can you modify the program?

Comment: yes. I am using mysql-connector-java.jar.

and in in my server.xml, i also set 

<!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your web application has a copy of the MySQL JDBC driver in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, the special [delegation rules for classloaders](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) used in Tomcat will select the web application's copy of the driver instead of the global one.

That will create two references on your application's classloader in the bootstrap classloader:

- The driver will be registered with `DriverManager` (in the bootstrap classloader),
- The driver will create a new thread with the `ContextClassLoader` set to the webapp classloader.

Both references can create a memory leak.

**Remark:** This happens even if you don't use a `DriverManager` directly, but some database pooling library (which will use `DriverManager` in the end) or if you define a JNDI `<Resource>` in your `<Context>`. Only the case of a `<Resource>` defined in the `<GlobalNamingResources>` is not affected.

To solve the problem you can:

- either remove the database driver from your `WEB-INF/lib` directory,
- reverse these changes when the application stops by calling `DriverManager.deregister`, e.g. in a ServletContextListener:

```java
public class JdbcDriverListener implements ServletContextListener {

   /**
    * Deregisters the JDBC drivers distributed with the application.
    */
   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
      final ClassLoader cl = event.getServletContext().getClassLoader();
      final Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
      while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
         final Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
         // We deregister only the classes loaded by this application's classloader
         if (driver.getClass().getClassLoader() == cl) {
            try {
               DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
               event.getServletContext().log("JDBC Driver deregistration failure.", e);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Registers the JDBC drivers distributed with the application.
    */
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
      Iterator<@NonNull Driver> driversIterator = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class).iterator();
      while (driversIterator.hasNext()) {
         try {
            // Instantiates the driver
            driversIterator.next();
         } catch (Throwable t) {
            event.getServletContext().log("JDBC Driver registration failure.", t);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:** I merge the information from the comments into the answer.

Comment: I'm using DB Pooling.

In Java program, I user initContext and enviromentContext. 
It will refer to the JDBC pool.

And in the server.xml, we define 

Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"

Comment: A database pool ends up calling `DriverManager`. If you configured the `<Resource>` in your application's `<Context>` it works the same way as if you used `DriverManager` in your application. Remove `mysql-connector-java.jar` from your application's `WEB-INF/lib` folder and the problem should stop.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you. After I remove the mysql.jar from WEB-INT/lib, the error not occured.

But I also made changes to server.xml where I use com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

I also need to change the Resource Type 

url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/aa?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Amsterdam&amp;useSSL=false"

Comment: I try this answer, and it didn't work, do I need to add @Component annotation