# I have method that return connection which is acquired my tomcat jndi, should I close DataSource object to prevent memory leak?Tomcat9

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector, tomcat9

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Final</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Final</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

First of all, I'm using mysql connector 8.0.24 version which is place in Tomcat/lib
I don't have lib in WEB-INF
I use Maven build tool[image: Target dir]
[image]

[image]
I have static method that return connection

```
public static Connection getConnection(){

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

And when I stop my app I get this
[image]
What can I do to resolve this problem? Do I need close DataSource object or Context object?Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The web application \[\] appears to have started a thread named \[Abandoned connection cleanup thread\] com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699985/the-web-application-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-abandoned-connect)

Comment: @flwd I put my jdbc mysl driver in Tomcat/lib but it did not solve the problem, btw I'm using mysql connector 8.0.24

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 9 error - mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056707/tomcat-9-error-mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I dont have WEB-INF/lib I have just edited post, Thank for information

Comment: @Justtoasktheneededquestions: most build tools populate `WEB-INF/lib` with the project dependencies when they create a WAR file. Which build tool are you using?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Im using maven build tool, I edited post thanks for correction

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  Added pom xml and target dir hierachy

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code and error messages, post them as code-formatted text.