# When I trying test Dao methods that use connection obtained from JNDI connection poll in Tomcat I get NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, junit, jndi

I have method which gets connection by using JNDI lookup.

Context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/UsersDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxTotal="30"
            maxIdle="15"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taksi_online"
            username="Bruce"
            password="givanchy"
            defaultAutoCommit="false"
    />
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/UsersDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

public static void dataSourceInit() throws NamingException {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        if(dataSource==null){
            dataSourceInit();
        }
       Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

I have simple test Dao methods which use method getConnection

```
class TaxiServiceCarTest {
    private OrderDao orderDao;
    private TaxiServiceOrder orderService;
    @BeforeEach
    void initTaxiService() {
        orderDao = mock(OrderDao.class);
        orderService = new TaxiServiceOrder(orderDao);
    }
    @Test
    void insertCar() throws MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException, SQLException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException, ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException {
        Order order = new Order();
        when(orderDao.insertOrder(any(Connection.class), any(Order.class))).thenReturn(true);
        assertTrue(orderService.insertOrder(order));
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test I get NoInitialContextException.ApplicationEXContainter It my custom exception.

```
com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.exception.ApplicationEXContainer$ApplicationCanNotChangeException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceOrder.insertOrder(TaxiServiceOrder.java:30)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceCarTest.insertCar(TaxiServiceCarTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.mysql.MySQLDAOFactory.dataSourceInit(MySQLDAOFactory.java:21)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.mysql.MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection(MySQLDAOFactory.java:27)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceOrder.insertOrder(TaxiServiceOrder.java:25)
    ... 66 more
```

Why does this problem occur?My webapp use this connection poll so I dont think I was wrong In configuring context file, the Context does not seem to get registered.

Comment: JUnit does not configure JNDI: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12545129/11748454).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank for answering It helped me a lot but I got new problem. For unit test I need pass Mysql connector to class path but If I do It I will get "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" because I have  a copy of the MySQL JDBC driver So what should I do?If i remove connector I can not do unit test but If it is in Class path and in Tomcat lib directory I get  "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" .

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz When I tried to add scrope attribute in maven My test haven't seen any mysql class driver.

Comment: Regarding the `mysql-cf-abandoned-connection-cleanup` thread, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66056707/11748454). The question is specific to Tomcat (whereas JUnit tests don't use any part of Tomcat), but you can perform a similar cleanup in an [`@AfterAll`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/AfterAll.html) method.