# Problem with JDBC driver on deployment after delete and recreate databse

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a problem with deploying the spring boot application after I delete the database and create new. When I deploy it I got an following exception:

> 29-Jan-2023 00:16:21.058 WARNING [main]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
> The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver
> [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
> application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
> been forcibly unregistered. 29-Jan-2023 00:16:21.059 WARNING [main]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
> The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
> [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it.
> This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

I read online, and I try the couple of methods and didn't work reference to the Stack Overflow answer: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059200/19219457)
When i move the MySQL driver to tomcat lib folder, I got another exception for class witch is not mark as entity:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: persistent class not known

Locally everything working fine. Any clues how to fix the issue, I don't have rights to restart the MySQL database at the moment and I search for fix.

From the answer I only create that class I am not sure if i need to call it somewhere.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered